# Как определить простое число JAVA

Tags: java

Нужно написать программу, которая при вводе числа с клавиатуры определяет простое оно или нет. Я не могу понять, как записать сравнение со всеми простыми числами.

Comment: Надо просто перебрать все простые числа от нуля до sqrt(N) и при делении нацело прерывать процесс.

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать один из т.н. "тестов простоты", например вероятностный тест Рабина-Миллера.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов если ему не нужна быстродейственность и не такие уж и большие числа, то самый простой тест Ферма. А так тестов на простоту достаточно, сам лично знаю штук 5.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, Рабин-Миллер прост, интересен и скорее всего более чем достаточен :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class NaturalNumbersCheck {

static int var = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    checkIsItANaturalNumber(n);
}
private static void checkIsItANaturalNumber(int n) {
    if (n > 1) {
        if (n % var != 0) {
            var++;
            checkIsItANaturalNumber(n);
        } else if (n % var == 0) {
            printIsItNaturalNumber(var, n);
        }
    }
}
private static void printIsItNaturalNumber(int var, int n) {
    if (var == n) {
        System.out.println(n + " is a natural number.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(n + " is not a natural number.");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы определить простоту не надо сравнивать со всеми простыми числами, достаточно выполнить тест простоты.
В Java уже реализован тест Рабина-Миллера в классe `BigInteger`.

```
Integer integer = 12311;
BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(integer);
boolean probablePrime = bigInteger.isProbablePrime((int) Math.log(integer));
System.out.println(probablePrime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужно сравнивать со всеми простыми числами. Вам нужно убедиться, что число не имеет других делителей, кроме 1 и самого себя.

К сожалению, в Java не силен, поэтому вот Вам код на С

```c
bool IsSimple(int ANum) {
  if (ANum < 2)
    return false;
  double s = sqrt(ANum)
  for (int i = 2; i <= s; i++) {
    if (ANum % i == 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Вы могли бы сократить число итераций вдвое, если бы не проверяли деление на четные числа (и, конечно, это далеко не последняя оптимизация, которую можно было применить, разумных кандидатов на простые числа - не более 6 из 30). И, кстати, двойка - вполне легальное простое число.

Comment: @Etki где у меня сказано, что двойка составное число?

Comment: а вот это уже я профакапился, да

Answer (score 0):

```
class PrimeNumber{
    private int number;
    private boolean check = true;

    public PrimeNumber(int num){
        number = num;
    }
    public boolean checkNum(){
        for(int i =2; i<number; i++){
            if(number%i==0){
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        } return check;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        boolean check;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            number = sc.nextInt();
        }while(number<=1);
        PrimeNumber prime = new PrimeNumber(number);
        check = prime.checkNum();
        System.out.println("this number is " + check);
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]